# WIndows 7 - Virtual PC - Printer redirection

Tags: windows-7, printer, redirection

Where can I set the printer redirection in Windows 7 Virtual PC?

I cannot find it and [Windows XP Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC#Windows_XP_Mode) does not have the printers that are installed locally on Windows 7.

I see everywhere on the Internet that one of the features is printer redirection, but I can't find where to set it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this document](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyId=62cd2e63-52f8-4cf5-a7d5-7abaab270451&displayLang=en):

Scenario 3: Print from a virtual machine

There are several methods you can use to make a printer available to a virtual machine. The methods you can use are affected by whether a printer driver is available for Windows 7 and whether the printer is a local USB printer or a network printer.

**To share a local USB printer**

1. Note 
   This method is appropriate when the printer driver is available for both the Windows 7 host operating system and the guest operating system. You only need to complete these steps once per virtual machine. This procedure assumes you have verified that the printer is working in the host operating system.
   Make sure the printer is turned on and that the printer driver is available for installation. For example, you can install the driver from the internet or from a CD.
   Redirect the printer to the virtual machine. From the virtual machine window, click USB and then click Attachdevice name.
2. Install the printer driver in the guest operating system. You can install the driver from the internet or from a CD.
3. Release the printer from the virtual machine. From the virtual machine window, click USB and then click Releasedevice name.
4. Restart the virtual machine. From the virtual machine window, click Action and then click Restart.
5. Navigate to the virtual machine desktop, and log on if necessary. (You will be logged in automatically if you saved the credentials.)
6. The printer will be available for use in both the host operating system and the guest operating system.

**To configure a network printer for a virtual machine**

1. Navigate to the virtual machine desktop, and log on if necessary. (You will be logged in automatically if you saved the credentials.)

Note 
The following steps are general, so the names of the buttons may differ from what is shown.

2. Open Control Panel, and then open Printers.
3. Click Add Printer. The Add Printer Wizard opens.
4. On the Local or Network Printer page, select the network printer option and complete the wizard.

If you are running Windows XP as the guest operating system, you must manually install the printer driver for each printer you want to use. The following steps describe this process.

**To install a printer driver in Windows XP**
1.  Click Start, and then click Printers and Faxes.

2. Under Printer Tasks, click Add a printer. The Add Printer Wizard opens.
3. On the Local or Network Printer page, select Local printer attached to this computer and clear Automatically detect and install my Plug and Play printer.
4. On the Select a Printer Port page, click the drop-down control and select one of the TS number ports and click Next.
5. On the Install Printer Software page, select Windows Update or Have Disk and complete the wizard.

**To print from a virtual machine**
1.  Navigate to the virtual machine desktop, and log on if necessary. (You will be logged in automatically if you saved the credentials.)

2. Do one of the following:
   From the desktop of the virtual machine, right-click a file and click Print.
   Open any application that includes a print option, and then use the print command.
3. All printers available to the virtual machine are listed. Select a printer, and then click OK.

In general, I would just share the host's printer over the (virtual) network and in the guest, connect to the network printer. I try to run my virtual machines / networks in the same way as I would physical ones - it saves me having to learn two different ways to do the same things.